# Running GNU/Linux on a tablet, as of November 2018

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, tablet-computer

There seems to be little information available about what distributions are able to operate tablets (tablet-computers). I'm specifically addressing 7in-10in "true" tablets, *not* hybrid laptops with touchscreen and detachable keyboard.

I've searched the web for several days (including this very site). I found much information, but:

- all of it is either obsolete, or so old that it's probably not relevant anymore. Example: the Ubuntu wiki still has pages about Ubuntu Touch, which has been abandoned by Canonical; I went to https://ubuntu-touch.io and https://ubports.com , but all pages are missing a date, and the FAQ refers to "16.04" as a future release whereas it seems to be released already.
- I found contradicting evidence: some people say tablets are closer to smartphones than to laptops, especially as regards proprietary drivers for the tablet peripherals; others say that x86-powered tablets can run GNU/Linux just like laptops do.

As an example I've skimmed through the openSUSE website and couldn't determine whether the current version is installable on a tablet, or under what conditions (regarding the tablet hardware).

Ubuntu Touch promotes only 4 devices, among which only one is a tablet! (The other 3 are smartphones.)

All this leads me to the conclusion that running GNU/Linux on a tablet is, at the time of this writing, either very delicate (but then, why so few up-to-date questions or pages on this subject?) or very straightforward (but then, why no mention at all of such an install on e.g. the openSUSE website?). I couldn't even find a relevant tag here. "tablet" refers to graphical tablets (digitizers), "tablet computer" didn't exist until I used it, "smartphone" isn't really relevant, "phablet" & "hybrid computer" wouldn't be if they existed...

So the question is: can you point to GNU/Linux distributions that explicitly support (some) tablets? A link to an *up-to-date* page stating the given distribution generally supports tablets, or listing supported models? (Something like https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/Nexus , which is now both obsolete because Ubuntu doesn't support Touch anymore and outdated because the last tests date back to more than 4 years...)

Comment: I see 4 votes to close my question. Voters are welcome to comment here to explain why. I could improve it maybe. I know my question is very open and calls for a long answer, but, well, not all Q&A are one-liners!

Comment: "Put on hold" and still no comment to support this. "Primarily opinion-based"? I'm wondering what part of my question calls for opinions... I'm asking what distributions support which tablets. No room for opinions there. The absence of a "tablet-computer" tag here is quite revealing about the lack of knowledge in this field!

Comment: Edited to rephrase parts of the text and add an explicit question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could clarify more your question. Usually tablets have ARM processor so any GNU/Linux for ARM architecture can work nice.
My suggestions:

1. https://archlinuxarm.org/
2. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM
3. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

Comment: (1/2) I will clarify with pleasure, can you tell me what's not clear? About your answer: "usually tablets have ARM processor" is a bit vague, and supporting a processor is not enough to make a device work AFAIK. Thank you for your links, but they don't clear up my doubts. Link 2 : "We don't directly support devices such as phones and tablets but it's not to say that without _the required kernel/bootloader know how_ that they don't work, it's just not our primary focus." (emphasis mine) Link 3 : "includes support for the very latest ARM-based _server systems_"

Comment: (2/2) Link 1 lists supported boards. It's not immediately clear if/which tablets are supported. I saw a Snapdragon-based board, and such processors seem to be rather frequent on tablets, but that's all I can tell. The only well-known devices I've found in the list are the Samsung Chromebooks, but they're computers, not tablets.

Comment: Please give me an exact tablet model so I would help you how to install GNU/Linux on it. By exact model I mean something like Samsung Series 7 Slate XE700T1A.

Comment: I'm clearly _not_ asking for instructions about configuring a particular model. I'm expecting a review of existing possibilities: what distributions support tablets? With _references_, e.g. webpages of those distributions which clearly state this fact.